Could the voices experienced by individuals with schizophrenia genuinely possess self-awareness?I
We lack a precise definition or physical model of self-awareness, but all humans seem to grasp it intuitively—we experience colors, pain, and other subjective qualia. Now consider a person diagnosed with schizophrenia who reports hearing voices in their head that, by some accounts, appear to “live a life of their own.” Is it conceivable that these voices could truly possess their own self-awareness? In other words, alongside the main personality (which we assume has its own self-awareness), might the voices themselves also have a genuine capacity to feel or experience, rather than simply imitating consciousness?

Can you provide references for these "accounts"? This is not how I understand schizophrenia at all.
